# How to solve equations involving reciprocal square roots of quadratics?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

$$\frac{2x-8}{\:\sqrt{2x^2-16x+34}}+\frac{2x-3}{\sqrt{2x^2-6x+5}}=0$$

Is it possible to solve this equations? If yes then how?

Comment: Surprisingly the answer is 7/3 only !

Comment: The equation has the form $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+4}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}=0$ which implies $sign(a)=-sign(b)$ and $a^2=4b^2$, together $a=-2b$ or $2x-8=-4x+6$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! This is quite easy:

$$\begin{align*}\frac{2x-8}{\sqrt{2x^2-16x+34}}+\frac{2x-3}{\sqrt{2x^2-6x+5}}&=0\\ \frac{2x-8}{\sqrt{2x^2-16x+34}}&=-\frac{2x-3}{\sqrt{2x^2-6x+5}}\\ \left(\frac{2x-8}{\sqrt{2x^2-16x+34}}\right)^2&=\left(\frac{2x-3}{\sqrt{2x^2-6x+5}}\right)^2\end{align*}$$ and so on. The result should be a *quadratic* given the comment that has corrected me!

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much

Comment: "*The result should be a quartic*" Actually, it's a quadratic. You can tell beforehand that the $4^{th}$ powers will cancel out, but once you do the calculations you'll find that the $3^{rd}$ powers also cancel out, leaving a simple quadratic to solve.